# Sorting an array within a dictionary by the array key's value in PHP

Tags: php, ios, json

This is sort of a two part question, but here's my PHP code below and I want to sort the business_hours by day in ascending order (0,1,...6). Is this easier in PHP or iOS (this is written for integration into an iOS app)?

Also, sidenote, my iOS developer says he has issues when returning the locations array dictionary like the one below. He'd rather have locations as a numbered array (JSON for [{},{},...] instead of what I have as {},{},...), but the issue is I simply can't find a way in PHP to do that for this application requirement. I specifically need to use array keys for adding the business hours to its corresponding location. I am doing a join of three tables to grab business hours and location id, so that the location id for the business hours matches the location id of the location itself; that seems to be the only way to get the two arrays to join for the JSON output array to work... You can see below, but let me know if I am wrong or if it would be easier for my iOS developer to just learn how to iterate through and return all array values for a multidimensional, associative array with keys. Please advise!

```
if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare($query)) {
            // initialise an array for the results 
            $result = array();
            if ( $stmt->execute(array($lat,$lat,$lng,$rest_price,$eat_in,$take_out,$delivery)) ) {
                        // loop through all values
                while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                    // Have we seen this menu before? If not, add it to the array
                    if ( !isset($result['locations'][$row['rest_id']]) ) {
                        $result['locations'][$row['rest_id']] = array(
                            'rest_id' => $row['rest_id'],
                            'user_id' => $row['user_id'],
                            'rest_name' => $row['rest_name'],
                            'lat' => $row['lat'],
                            'lng' => $row['lng'],
                            'rest_price' => $row['rest_price'],
                            'rest_rating' => $row['rest_rating'],
                            'rest_genre' => $row['rest_genre'],
                            'eat_in' => $row['eat_in'],
                            'take_out' => $row['take_out'],
                            'delivery' => $row['delivery'],
                            'rest_img' => $row['rest_img'],
                            'user_img' => $row['user_img'],
                            'business_hours' => array()
                        );
                    }
                    // Add the ingredient.
                    // remove all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leave 0 (zero) values
                    $result['locations'][$row['rest_id']]['business_hours'][] = array_filter(array(
                        'day' => $row['day'],
                        'open_time' => $row['open_time'],
                        'close_time' => $row['close_time']
                    ), 'strlen');
                }

                // print results if not null
                if( $result != null ) {       
                    // print success. no error.
                    $result['error'] .= '';     
                    echo json_encode($result);
                    //print_r($result);
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'No locations exist in your area'));
                }
```

Array

```
(
[locations] => Array
    (
        [67] => Array
            (
                [rest_id] => 67
                [user_id] => 19
                [rest_name] => The Ninja
                [lat] => 34.1516
                [lng] => -106.685591
                [rest_price] => 2
                [rest_rating] => 3.5
                [rest_genre] => Japanese
                [eat_in] => 1
                [take_out] => 1
                [delivery] => 1
                [rest_img] => 88/image11.png
                [user_img] => image595.png
                [business_hours] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [day] => 4
                                [open_time] => 09:00:00
                                [close_time] => 16:30:00
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [day] => 1
                                [open_time] => 10:00:00
                                [close_time] => 17:00:00
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [day] => 6
                                [open_time] => 12:00:00
                                [close_time] => 18:00:00
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [day] => 3
                                [open_time] => 10:00:00
                                [close_time] => 17:00:00
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [day] => 0
                                [open_time] => 00:00:00
                                [close_time] => 00:00:00
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [day] => 5
                                [open_time] => 10:00:00
                                [close_time] => 17:00:00
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [day] => 2
                                [open_time] => 10:00:00
                                [close_time] => 17:00:00
                            )

                    )

            )// more arrays occur after this...

    )

[error] => 
)
```

JSON

```
{"locations":{"67":{"rest_id":"67","user_id":"19","rest_name":"The Ninja","lat":"","lng":"","rest_price":"2","rest_rating":"3.5","rest_genre":"Japanese","eat_in":"1","take_out":"1","delivery":"1","rest_img":"","user_img":"","business_hours":[{"day":"6","open_time":"12:00:00","close_time":"18:00:00"},{"day":"3","open_time":"10:00:00","close_time":"17:00:00"},{"day":"0","open_time":"00:00:00","close_time":"00:00:00"},{"day":"5","open_time":"10:00:00","close_time":"17:00:00"},{"day":"2","open_time":"10:00:00","close_time":"17:00:00"},{"day":"4","open_time":"09:00:00","close_time":"16:30:00"},{"day":"1","open_time":"10:00:00","close_time":"17:00:00"}]},{},...},"error":""}
```

Comment: Post an actual instance of the JSON string, shortened as much as possible, and I'll take a look.  In other words, I'd like to see a JSON string that starts at the top level, and includes the `[67] => Array` entry with the `[0] => Array` and `[1] => Array` subentries, but doesn't have the other subentries for [67], and doesn't have all the rest of the entries [89], [99], etc.

Comment: done. hopefully that provides all the result outputs anyone would need to see to understand. I guess my iOS developer really likes it when he sees an array that is like `{"locations":[{},{},...],"error":""}` and I usually do all the heavy lifting server-side with PHP, but having an issue sorting the business hours by the numerical day and whether or not I need the array in a particular format (right vs wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that took forever (partly because the json string wasn't valid since it had a `...` in it, but w/e).

Your developer prefers an array-of-dictionaries like this `{"locations":[{},{},...],"error":""}` instead of a dictionary-of-dictionaries like this 
`{"locations":{"67":{},"89":{},...} ,"error":""}` because the array-of-dictionaries fits nicely into the iOS table view paradigm.  However, it's only one line of code to convert the dictionary-of-dictionaries into an array-of-dictionaries, e.g.

```
NSArray *locationAllValues = [locationDictionary allValues];
```

So the only question is one of performance.  Do you force the server to do more work to generate the preferred format, or do you let the mobile device do some of the work?

When parsing the JSON data, I recommend using the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option so that the arrays and dictionaries are mutable. That makes it easier to sort the `day` arrays.  And yes, it's easy to sort the arrays in iOS.  Here's a full set of code that creates an array of dictionaries from the input JSON. The input to the code is an `NSData` object that contains the JSON string downloaded from the network.  The array of dictionaries is sorted by the `rest_id`, and within each dictionary, the array of `business_hours` is sorted by `day`.

Note that the code has no error checking, other than checking for `nil` after the call to `JSONObjectWithData`. This is just proof of concept, not production code.  Use at your own risk.

```
- (NSArray *)parseAndSortJsonResponse:(NSData *)data
{
    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    if ( !jsonData )
    {
        NSLog( @"Invalid JSON string" );
        return( nil );
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *locationDictionary = jsonData[@"locations"];
    NSArray *locationAllValues = [locationDictionary allValues];

    NSArray *locationsArray = [locationAllValues sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
    {
        NSDictionary *d1 = obj1;
        NSDictionary *d2 = obj2;

        int v1 = [d1[@"rest_id"] intValue];
        int v2 = [d2[@"rest_id"] intValue];

        if ( v1 < v2 )
            return( NSOrderedAscending );
        else if ( v1 > v2 )
            return( NSOrderedDescending );
        else
            return( NSOrderedSame );
    }];

    for ( NSMutableDictionary *location in locationsArray )
    {
        NSArray *array = location[@"business_hours"];
        NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
        {
            NSDictionary *d1 = obj1;
            NSDictionary *d2 = obj2;

            int v1 = [d1[@"day"] intValue];
            int v2 = [d2[@"day"] intValue];

            if ( v1 < v2 )
                return( NSOrderedAscending );
            else if ( v1 > v2 )
                return( NSOrderedDescending );
            else
                return( NSOrderedSame );
        }];
        [location setObject:sorted forKey:@"business_hours"];
    }

    NSLog( @"%@", locationsArray );

    return( locationsArray );
}
```

Comment: @jflay I've amended my remarks concerning the array-of-dictionaries.